# Rails Navbar application controller variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a value that I use inside the navbar. Think of it as some sort of low skill notification. On the root page I have access to it because I define it inside that method:

```
@conversations = Conversation.where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?",current_user.id,current_user.id)
```

If I move to a different method(page), the scope of that variable will be out and I'd have to redefine it again.

How can I define this variable as a cross-controller variable as every page has the same navbar?

```
<li> Conversations <%= @conversations.count %> </li>
```

Comment: Define it in `application_controller.rb`

Comment: I tried, but I don't have access to `current_user` of devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ApplicationController**

```
....
before_action: :conversation_count

def conversation_count
  @conversations = 
      Conversation.where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?",current_user.id,current_user.id) if current_user.present?
end
...
```

**Navbar** Show count only if user is loggedin

```
<ul>
  <li> About </li>
  <% if current_user.present %>
  <li>Conversations <%= @conversations.count %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**Navbar** Show count irrespective of user is logged in or no

```
<ul>
  <li> About </li>
  <li>Conversations <%= @conversations.try(:count).to_i %></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not have it in a method .. . It s working. Replace `before_action:` with `before_action`, otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Are you being serious? You went out of your way to criticise suggesting you use application controller, then accept this answer? lol

Comment: @Mark ??? You did nothing helpful. Your answer did nothing helpful. Next time comment, don't answer. You can see from his answer how one should look like.  I was using the application controller, but in a wrong way.

Comment: That is what 2 separate people asked you to do, however you informed both of them they were wrong, and asked why the second was bothering to repeat the information. Hence my amusement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the navbar in the layouts/application.html.erb and the rest of the content by calling the yield block so you are actually not changing the navbar based on controller(It is fixed).

Also assign the variable in the application_controller's method so as to access it throughout the other controllers.

If current_user is not accessible from application_controller may be you have to restart your server(but usually it is accessible).

**use**

if current_user.present?

**instead of**

if current_user.present

question mark is missing

Answer (score -1):

As someone else said, current_user works in application controller.

If you copy and paste whatever code you have from your conversations controller to your application controller, you'll have access to it from every controller than inherits from application controller (all of them unless you specify otherwise).

Comment: You just provided as an answer what Pavan suggested in the comments. And as I said, I get an error saying that 'current_user' is not defined.

Comment: That's because what Pavan said is factually correct. I thought to highlight the inheritance issue in case that was your problem. Can you post the exact code you're putting in your application controller, and the error message you receive?